Geerhardus von Rad's work abbreviated 'ThW' by Hans-Joachim Kraus in his commentary on Psalm 3
In reading through the text Psalms 1-59 by Hans-Joachim Kraus, he references a work by G. von Rad with the abbreviation 'ThW' (Psalm 3, p140). For the life of me, I've been unable to figure out this reference and the accompanying excerpts he uses in his commentary on Psalm 3. Perhaps someone in this community is able to point me in the right direction so I can understand the context of quotes located in 'ThW.'

Did the book not contain a list of its abbreviations?

Yes it did: pp. 545-548. Quite a few 'Th_' but no 'ThW' for some odd reason — maybe an oversight by the editor(?).

I emailed Fortres Press hoping they'd be able to shed some light on this.
